# How do you revoke someone else's PAT?

Tags: azure-devops

If I am the Project Collection Administrator in dev.azure.com for a particular organization, then how do I revoke someone else's Personal Access Token?

Comment: I'd expect you wouldn't be able to do that, but you can revoke the persons rights. that would stop the PAT from working (or block the person)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to do it by following these steps using Postman:

1. First we need to get the subject descriptor, which is the user’s SID in Azure AD:

   `GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/users?api-version=5.1-preview.1`
2. Now we need to list of the PATs for that user. (Lists of all the session token details of the personal access tokens (PATs) for a particular user:

   `GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/tokenadmin/personalaccesstokens/{subjectDescriptor}?api-version=5.0-preview.1`

We got the {*subjectDescriptor*} in the "*description*" field in step one and this is the SID of the Azure AD user.

3. Now we finally revoke that PAT for the particular user: (Revokes the listed OAuth authorizations.

   `POST https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/tokenadmin/revocations?api-version=5.0-preview.1`

The "authorizationId" that we got in the results from step 2 need to be input the POST request as a JSON object. It is an array below, so that it supports multiple revocations.

```
[
 {
   "authorizationId":  "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
 }
]
```

Comment: Glad to here you solved it and kindly share the solution! Please mark it as the answer so that it could help more people who met the same problem. Thanks!

Comment: Fantastic, this works very well using Postman (with very minor correction of an extra bracket). However, I highly suggest to use the Powershell script that @YangShen-MSFT has shared in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

> how do I revoke someone else's Personal Access Token?

This is acutually provided in MSDN documentation [Revoke personal access tokens for organization users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/admin-revoke-user-pats?view=azure-devops).

If you are the PCA of your organization, please follow the doc [Revoke PATs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/admin-revoke-user-pats?view=azure-devops#revoke-pats) to revoke PATs for your organization users.

Use the [Token Revocations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokenadministration/token%20revocations/revoke%20authorizations?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) or the [PowerShell script](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-script-samples/tree/master/PowerShell/TokenAdmin) provided to call the REST API.