# How to revoke an azure DevOps token with only the token value known?

Tags: azure-devops, authorization

I wonder how I can revoke a PAT token in Azure DevOps which I know only the actual token value of.

The GUI lets me remove my own tokens as long as I know their name, and via API it seems to be possible to remove tokens if their identifier is known only (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokenadmin/revocations/revoke%20authorizations?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

If only the token value is known, I would neither know the user it belongs to, nor its id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder how I can revoke a PAT token in Azure DevOps which I know only the actual token value of.

**Azure DevOps doesn't support revoking PAT simply by its value.**

With a value alone, Azure Devops has no way to determine which PAT the value belongs to. The name-and-value pairs can only be seen when creating PATs.

In Azure Devops, we can revoke PAT via web portal or REST API. And if you want to revoke a PAT by REST API, you need to know its `"authorizationId"`.

If you have questions about how to get `"authorizationId"`. Click [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59770400/how-do-you-revoke-someone-elses-pat) for detailed information.

Note that when you use REST API to revoke PAT, you need to use OAuth2 authentication. Click [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops) for detailed information and methods.